# Using LaTex in Matplotlib legend

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I try to annotate my graph with Matplotlib `legend` using this simple code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

q_range = np.linspace(0.01,1,num=100)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(q_range, q_range**(-0.4))
ax.legend(r"$q^{-0.4}$")
plt.show()
```

Why my outcome is a single $ sign?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the label of your plot and then create the legend:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

q_range = np.linspace(0.01,1,num=100)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(q_range, q_range**(-0.4), label = r"$q^{-0.4}$")
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```